# Select column, if blank select from another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

How does one detect whether a field is blank (not null) and then select another field if it is?

What I really need is a IsBlank function that works the same as IsNull but with with blanks.

REPLACE doesn't work with blanks, COALESCE only works with NULLS.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

How about combining COALESCE and NULLIF.

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(SomeColumn,''), ReplacementColumn)
FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: Interesting...can it be easily extended to work with 3 columns?

Comment: Answer - yes you can: `COALESCE(NULLIF(Address2,''), NULLIF(Address3,''), Address4)`

Comment: Moving the answer to yours as it is more elegant than the Case statement.

Comment: It is unreal how much this helped me.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a `CASE` statement for this

```
select 
Case WHEN Column1 = '' OR Column1 IS NULL OR LEN (TRIM (Column1))  = 0 
     THEN Column2 
     ELSE Column1 END as ColumnName
from TableName
```

Comment: This is what I had got on my own but is very ungainly.

Comment: I tried that but was somehow getting duplicate rows added.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: You can't use `IF()` in mssql.

Use an IF statement in the SELECT portion of your SQL:

```
SELECT IF(field1 != '', field1, field2) AS myfield FROM ...
```

Comment: Nice, but if I need to work more than 2 columns will be a pain.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working: `SELECT IF(Address2!='', Address2, Address3) AS Address FROM Sites` gives Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Comment: Okay, I'm a total dumbass and getting confused with mysql. `IF()` only seems to work with mysql, so rather use `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END` as above. I'll leave this here as a warning to others :)

Answer (score 2):

You could always write an isBlank() function, something like

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION isBlank
(
    @CheckExpression varchar, @ReplacementExpression varchar
)
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
    IF @CheckExpression IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF @CheckExpression='' or LEN(@CheckExpression) = 0
        RETURN @ReplacementExpression
    ELSE
        RETURN @CheckExpression
    END

    RETURN @ReplacementExpression
END
GO
```

Comment: I assume you could make it support *N* number of expressions since COALESCE does anyway via case statement like Raj More.