# Using IF in SELECT without referring to any column

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I've tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747768/1525840) (to a different problem that what I have). However, I'm getting the error telling me that the syntax is incorrect near *IF*.

```
select if(1 < 2, 3, 4) as Reply 
from Unit
```

The above is the exact syntax I'm using (the table Unit exists but has nothing to do with the values, of course. Sometimes I just wish to be able to manipulate some columns for better visibility when I play in SQL Studio.

Please note that I'm **not** asking about how to coalesce nor how to handle null values. If it appears like if I am, then either you've misunderstood the question or I haven't been clear with my explanation. Sorry about that in advance.

Comment: More recent versions of SQL Server support `iif()` (for, what is in my opinion, a misguided effort to be compatible with Access).  You should use the ANSI standard `CASE` for this logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Did you really mean *if* with two *i*'s in it? Cute syntax, in such case.

Comment: @Konrad Worth noting the answer you link to explicitly states that it doesn't work with MSSQL. That's why, as zaratustra states in their answer, you should use CASE.

Comment: @AndyNichols Well, it stated that it **could** when I read it because my eyes missed the negation, haha. Of course, now that you point that out, I see my obvious mistake. Stupid eyes...   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten . . . Yes, I really do mean `iif()` with two "i"s.  Learn to use `case`.  You might imagine that I think there are way more important things that SQL Server developers could do than implement Access functions.  (Aggregate string concatenation anyone?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the case clause:

```
select 
  case when 1 < 2 
    then 3 
    else 4 end as Reply 
from Unit
```

Or if you only wish to see the result once (as opposed to for each row in the table):

```
select
  case when 1 < 2 then 3 else 4 end as Reply
```

Comment: +1 for brevity and clarity. I took the liberty to add a small thingy too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the syntax you are looking for, it works from sqlserver 2012:

```
SELECT IIF( 1 < 2, 3, 4)
```

The syntax is:

[IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(IIF_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

Comment: Unfortunately, one of my environments is SQL Server Tyrannosaurus Rex so I'll have to *CASE* my way through. Nevertheless, I'll swiiiitch to *IIIIF* statement (typo intended) as soon as we get on the right side of the millennium for **all** our servers.